# How to make array of spheres float on a wave?

Tags: modifiers

I need something like on this PS5 presentation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkC0l4iekYo
Array of spheres floating on a way. I'm actually using 3ds max, but couldn't find a respective site. But since all 3d software is somewhat similar, I hope I'll be able to replicate blender tutors in 3dsmax

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is particles on surfaces that moves with a Displace modifier, but it seems a bit more complicated than that

Comment: maybe the molecular addon will work for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HVJzdROIs0